# Dynamic Div Element vs Hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of related questions. I am tasked with developing a page to generate poll questions. When creating the poll, I need to add new answers one at a time (as opposed to having, lets say 10 options and the poll creator only having two choices). Each answer will be a div that has multiple elements (such as text, image). When typing in the answer to one question, the next div will show up (so there is no need for a button that says "add question" So, it seems there are three ways to go.

1. load the max number of possible choices and hide them all (but the first) and unhide as needed.) I guess this is loading things that might not be used--but is that really a big deal?
2. JQuery and create fields on the fly. More efficient I suppose but a pain that if the browsers back but is used, they are gone when coming back to the page--probably a rare occurrence.
3. Use AJAX to load each new question. Seems like a danger with responsiveness if the new question is slow to load due to a DB call.

In addition to the above "best practice" for this situation I have another question, assuming I go with #2.

I created jsfiddle for how I would do this 
https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/uf9qfm53/21/

```
    var nlst="<li>Appended item<button class=\"up\">up</button></li>"
    $("#myList").append(nlst);
```

I know I can use the clone but in addition to adding/removing questions, i also need to move them up down and I was going crazy trying to get this to work. Using the list.append is nice and simple. Since each div containing question will be identical, I am fine writing out the code for the whole div and appending. In fact, I kind of like the readability of it.

BUT, when creating the new list item, the up/down buttons dont work. I think this is because the "up" class is not properly loaded due to the quotes. I have tried escaping the quotes but cant seem to get this to work.

So, can anyone help me understand the best way to add new question and if it is JQuery style, how can I get the generated buttons to work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .on method.
It binds events to all items (even those which are created later - it listens for them).

So instead of

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){});
```

use

```
$(document).on('click', '.someClass', function(){});
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ukys71m/

Comment: Hey, that works! Thanks so much. Now,  I think I can get this working overall all. So, my question then is: is this the best way to add new choices for a question? The only concerns are really just that 1) someone doesn have JS (unlikely?) and even if they dont I can direct to a form with 10 preset divs. and 2) if you leave the page with the browsers back button and then come back, the dynamic divs are gone. What is the thinking for best practice in this situation? JQuery or load, lets say 20 divs (hidden) and unhide as needed). Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I found another fiddle and was able to modify it slightly to do what I need:add/remove/move up/move down(I will add later). This is nice since it is a clone it renames the ids for me. (Although I dont quite follow the logic but it works). Anyway, the one problem is that the UP button doesnt work on the first click. But it works fine after that first click. This is the case for any new clone. How can I get it so that the UP button works on the first click?

Comment: Im pretty much done now except for one issue. Sometimes, it the up/down buttons just dont work on the first try. The buttons are identical to the clone/remove so I just dont know what the cause is. The updated fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/msith718/jL6cfedf/27/  any thoughts? it seems to be that any new clone takes two clicks to go up/down.